# If my particles are rendered as objects, how can I convert them into objects?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, particles

As I said in the title, I am trying to to convert a particle system its own individual mesh. I looked up online and saw there was supposed to be a “convert” option in the modifier’s tab. At first, I thought it was weird that I didn’t get this option and got “make instances real” instead, but after playing around, I found out the convert option was only available for hair particles rendered as paths. I tried clicking "apply" and "make instances real", but none led to the desired result. So is it possible to convert particles rendered as objects into their own meshes? If it is, how can I do it? If not, what alternatives do I have?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with "Make Instances Real"?